Will glass bottle survive being thrown into water?
Will this glass bottle survive, being thrown off a $15 \,\text{m}$ tall bridge onto water, assuming it will hit the water at the worst possible angle?

The glass bottle is well built, has a size of $1 \,\text{L}$ and is empty (see picture)

It is thrown with medium to strong force in a upward and forward angle, not directly at the water (See sketch)

The bridge is $15 \,\text{m}$ tall

The water is a slow-flowing river

Assuming the bottle will hit the water at the worst possible angle for survivability





It is hard to answer a question like this. If you hit the bottle with a hammer, will it break? It depends on how strong the bottle is, how hard the hammer is, what the worst possible angle is, and so on. It is easier to try the experiment.

I don't see how this is homework.

how heavy is the bottle? what will you put into it?

@paulina it weighs about 600g and is only filled with some sheets of paper.

I mean, you could calculate the force the water surface will exert on the bottle upon impact using the equations of motion, some fluid dynamics, and newton's laws. But I think you should be on the safe side just throwing it and seeing what happens. If it should really break, at least you know.

Thank you. Yes, I'd be interested in how to calculate these things.
